# Hacer la diagonal de una matriz 0. Python

Tags: python, matrices

Buenas a todos,

Me gustaría poder hacer la diagonal de una matriz igual a 0 con algún tipo de comando, ¿alguien sabe cómo?¿existe algún numpy que pueda hacerlo?
por ejemplo ASÍ:

```
     [,0] [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[0,]    0    0    1    1    0
[1,]    1    0    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

La diagonal esta compuesta por 0

Muchas gracias.

Comment: una matriz=0? a que te refieres con eso?

Comment: quiero decir que la diagonal sea igual a 0, por ejemplo esto:
     [,0] [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[0,]    0    0    1    1    0
[1,]    1    0    1    1    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0

Comment: He modificado la pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te refieres a que quieres que la diagonal tenga puros 0's si se puede realizar con numpy, observa este ejemplo:

```
a = np.zeros((3, 3),int) #Inicializo una matriz
np.fill_diagonal(a,5) # Relleno la diagonal con un valor especifico
```

Resumiendo, bastaria con agregar

```
np.fill_diagonal(matriz,0)
```

Comment: Muuuchas gracias :)